# Gradle 4.10.3 Building Android apk error,com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, android-sdk-2.3

Compiling apk problems

debug mode when building Android apk error, hope to give some suggestions to solve this error, the error information is as follows

```
`Error: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException`
```

Development environment

JDK version: 1.8.0_341

Android SDK version: android-30

Android NDK version: 19.2.5345600

Gradle Build version: 3.2.0

Gradle version: 4.10.3

Cocos Creater version: 2.4.6

Error log

```
17:38:32.054 [INFO] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform] Jar input D:\cocos_workspace\ydclient\build\jsb-default\frameworks\cocos2d-x\cocos\platform\android\java\libs\com.android.vending.expansion.zipfile.jar
17:38:32.264 [ERROR] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform] java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```